# Which software should I download to generate GNU GPG Key on mac?

Tags: macos, gpg

I am registering to Keybase and they need GNU GPG Key. I uploaded the SSH one but it did not work. Can you help me in this regard?`

I am using `10.11.6`

Comment: @VladimirBotka Uncertain about duplication. I am looking which software should I download to generate it on mac.

Comment: I've edited your question. The question is: Which software should I download to generate GNU GPG Key on mac? unix tag deleted. macos tag added. Please confirm the edit.

Comment: @VladimirBotka Done with that.